How do I change a, programmatically created, button's appearance and XML attributes?
I am currently creating a task list where I am populating a linear layout with buttons depending on a list of TasksMy list of Tasks with the buttons hand crafted to what they're supposed to look like
The linear Layout is in a scroll box, so that it hopefully can go beyond the blue rectangle and buttons
The numbers on the right arer their own scrollbox linear layout set up, and they thankfully behave properly,  and look as they should by giving them their font values etc
In the image is basically what the buttons are supposed to look like, when I make them through the designer and change the attributes, the issue is then making Buttons in kotlin adhere to this style/format
for ((index,task) in taskList.withIndex())
        {
            val styleContext = ContextThemeWrapper(this, R.style.TaskButton)

            val newButton = Button(styleContext)

            // setTintList also does not work
            newButton.background.setTint(Color.TRANSPARENT)

            //newButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)

            //newButton.layoutParams = placeholderTaskButton.layoutParams

            // we have to scale the TextSize down to the sp value that would be displayed in the XML attribute to avoid misized text
            // ScaledDensity is deprecated, so we have to divide it using this alternative method
            /*val scaleValue = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 1.0f, resources.displayMetrics)
            val scaledPixelSize : Float = placeholderTaskButton.textSize / scaleValue

            newButton.background = placeholderTaskButton.background
            newButton.text = task
            newButton.textAlignment = placeholderTaskButton.textAlignment
            newButton.textSize = scaledPixelSize
            newButton.id = index
            newButton.isAllCaps = false*/

            newButton.text = task

            taskLayout.addView(newButton)

            newButton.setOnClickListener() {
                newButton.text = "works"
            }
        }

this code snippet is basically a mash of all the solutions ive tried, in the base OnCreate it sets you up with
as you can see, a mix of all sorts of manual delegation, the current solution ive tried is to extract the button as a style and attempt to apply it with a Wrapper but it ignores, for seemingly no reason, certain variables:
text alignment off, ignoring background tint, avoiding allcaps requires setting the boolean (which the handcrafted buttons dont need)
Edit: i have at least been able to somewhat fix the alignment, in the designer theres default paddings in the hint text i.e padding left 34 dp, top 6 dp and bottom 6 dp. Which appears to be what the designer buttons adhere to, but not the programming created butttons
Adding these to the style fixed my alignment issue, so they all adhere to these padding values in the hint text I seeemed to be using coincidentally as I worked.
heres the style for reference:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <style name="TaskButton">
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:paddingLeft">24dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingBottom">6dp</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundTint">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="rippleColor">@color/black</item>
        <item name="android:textAlignment">textStart</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
        <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
    </style>
</resources>

The style is the closest ive been, the really annoying part is I can add another button in the designer and give it the style, and it will be looking as it should...
This is what I want to achieve in Kotlin, so I can generate buttons by the tasks present
as mentioned I tried:
manually setting everything: but it would ignore any angle of trying to change background tint. Setting background did change it, but this would also remove the ripple
changing the style using a context wrapper: this is the closest I've gotten but it would ignore the background tint once again for the grey default
storing one of the hard coded buttons and attempting to match the values with the new instantiate in code button: similar issue, some things just wouldnt gel right, and required really weird fiddling like calculating scaled pixel and disabling all caps to avoid, big capitalized text
EDit: I have also in the interim of submitting this question, learned how to get the button in via making the button its own layout and using inflate, though my question still stands, with Instantiate being such a common keyword in similar languages to make instances of an object with all of its appearance, parameters and properties, I feel like putting it into a layout xml is roundabout and weirdly cheating? Surely theres a more common and direct way?
val inflatedLayout = LayoutInflater.from(styleContext).inflate(R.layout.testbutton, null)
val inflateButton : Button = inflatedLayout.findViewById(R.id.layoutTaskButton)

taskLayout.addView(inflateButton)

